# Laravel routing not working correctly for static page

Tags: php, laravel, routes

**/resources/views/layout/partials/nav.blade.php**

```
<li><a href="/LaravelCrud/public/tasks/about">About</a></li>
```

**/routes/web.php**

```
Route::resource('tasks', 'TaskController');
```

**/app\Http/Controllers/TaskController.php**

```
    public function about()
    {       
         return view('tasks.about');
    }
```

**/resources/views/tasks/about.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout.layout')
     @section('content')
      <div><h3>hello world </h3></div>
@endsection
```

**Getting this error**

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change url to route and defined it into route file.

```
<li><a href="{{ route('task.about') }}">About</a></li>
```

Route.php

```
Route::get('task/about', 'TaskController@about')->name('task.about');
```

If you want to use direct URL then you may use `{{ url('task/about')}}` instead of `{{ route('task.about') }}`

**Note:** Because as you defined `resource` in web.php file it contains many methods and URL.

```
Route::resource('tasks','eventcontroller');

Verb          Path                         Action  Route Name
GET           /tasks                       index   tasks.index
GET           /tasks/create                create  tasks.create
POST          /tasks                       store   tasks.store
GET           /tasks/{tasks}               show    tasks.show
GET           /tasks/{tasks}/edit          edit    tasks.edit
PUT|PATCH     /tasks/{tasks}               update  tasks.update
DELETE        /tasks/{tasks}               destroy tasks.destroy
```

Comment: **Getting Error**
`    public function setLocale($locale)
    {
        $locale = preg_replace_callback('/[-_]([a-z]{2,})/', function ($matches) {
            // _2-letters is a region, _3+-letters is a variant
            return '_'.call_user_func(strlen($matches[1]) > 2 ? 'ucfirst' : 'strtoupper', $matches[1]);
        }, strtolower($locale));
 
        if ($this->loadMessagesFromFile($locale)) {
            parent::setLocale($locale);
 
            return true;
        }
 
        return false;
    }
}
 `

Comment: *Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1882092160 bytes)*

Comment: Great Now your route is calling but this error is coming from another function as you defined middleware where this setLocale function is called please check your middleware and try to resolve it something is wrong here,

Comment: Here I forgot to add comma please check the updated answer. `->name('task.about');`

Comment: I have checked it seems everything ok in Middleware.
- EncryptCookies.php
- RedirectIfAuthenticated.php
- TrimStrings.php
- TrustProxies.php
- VerifyCsrfToken.php